# How to install vim-latex on a Mac?

Tags: installing, mac, vim

Can someone please help with installing vim with the latex plugin? I've tried searching online for easier instructions, but I can't find anything. I have very little experience with terminal and I have no idea how to do this.

What I've done is just download [the file](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download). I created a ~/.vim directory, but beyond that, I'm completely lost.

**Update:** I'm running Mac OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions?  http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download#installation  and settings recommendations?  http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html

Comment: @rickhg12hs yeah, of course. THat was the first thing I did. I don't understand all of it. I'm not very experienced with setting up stuff like this

Comment: Okay, not sure what your current state is.  Can you run vim normally?  I.e., it's installed and runs correctly?  Do you know how to unzip files and have the contents end up where you want?  Is there anything in .vimrc already?

Comment: @rickhg12hs to be safest let's just say i have vim downloaded and unzipped and that's it

Comment: Saw your other post asking about editors for Mac.  Based on your specific list of requirements, is vim even in the running?  Seems like you would have bypassed it quickly.

Comment: @rickhg12hs from what I've read it is. I started with a list of possible candidates and eliminated ones that didn't meet any of my must-haves. Is there something about vim that doesn't meet one of the requirements I listed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suppose you already have Vim installed in your operating system.

Usually, the installation is very straightforward for every operating system. For Macs, we have MacVim, and AFAIK  two options are available:

- Getting the correct MacVim version for your operating system [in the project website](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/), unzip the archive file and drag `MacVim.app` to your `Applications` folder.
- If you use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), there's already a formula for MacVim available, so you can run

  ```
  brew install macvim
  ```

  and MacVim will be deployed.

Now, back to `vim-latex`.

I don't use it, but I can provide a very clean way of deploying plugins for Vim. The solution relies on Tim Pope's awesome [[image: Pathogen]`pathogen`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) plugin, which manage our `runtimepath` very easily.

First of all, open your terminal and type the following:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle
```

This will create two directories (and even the parent `.vim` directory, if it doesn't exist), `autoload` and `bundle`  inside `.vim`. Now we are half-way done.

Now, let's type this command:

```
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

This command will download `pathogen.vim` from Tim's repository and deploy it inside the `autoload` directory.

Now let's edit `.vimrc` to call `pathogen` for us. Type this command:

```
open -e ~/.vimrc
```

and add the following lines, preferably in the beginning:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

...
<the rest of the file>
...
```

<sub>**Note:** The only required line for `pathogen` to work is the first one, the other two are just some goodies I recommend. `:)`</sub>

Now, if you want to deploy *any* Vim plugin, just extract it and put the extracted directory under `~/.vim/bundle`. That's it.

For example, I got this file, `vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956.tar.gz`. I'll extract it, and the result is as follows:

```
vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956
├── compiler
│   └── tex.vim
├── doc
│   ├── catalog.xml
│   ├── db2vim
│   │   ├── db2vim
│   │   ├── domutils.py
│   │   └── textutils.py
│   ├── imaps.txt
│   ├── latexhelp.txt
│   ├── latex-suite-chunk.xsl
│   ├── latex-suite-common.xsl
│   ├── latex-suite.css
│   ├── latex-suite-quickstart.css
│   ├── latex-suite-quickstart.txt
│   ├── latex-suite-quickstart.xml
│   ├── latex-suite.txt
│   ├── latex-suite.xml
│   ├── latex-suite.xsl
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── Makefile.in
│   ├── README
│   └── README.new
├── ftplugin
│   ├── bib_latexSuite.vim
│   ├── latex-suite
│   │   ├── bibtex.vim
│   │   ├── bibtools.py
│   │   ├── brackets.vim
│   │   ├── compiler.vim
│   │   ├── custommacros.vim
│   │   ├── diacritics.vim
│   │   ├── dictionaries
│   │   │   ├── dictionary
│   │   │   └── SIunits
│   │   ├── elementmacros.vim
│   │   ├── envmacros.vim
│   │   ├── folding.vim
│   │   ├── macros
│   │   │   └── example
│   │   ├── main.vim
│   │   ├── mathmacros-utf.vim
│   │   ├── mathmacros.vim
│   │   ├── multicompile.vim
│   │   ├── outline.py
│   │   ├── packages
│   │   │   ├── accents
│   │   │   ├── acromake
│   │   │   ├── afterpage
│   │   │   ├── alltt
│   │   │   ├── amsmath
│   │   │   ├── amsthm
│   │   │   ├── amsxtra
│   │   │   ├── arabic
│   │   │   ├── array
│   │   │   ├── babel
│   │   │   ├── bar
│   │   │   ├── biblatex
│   │   │   ├── bm
│   │   │   ├── bophook
│   │   │   ├── boxedminipage
│   │   │   ├── caption2
│   │   │   ├── cases
│   │   │   ├── ccaption
│   │   │   ├── changebar
│   │   │   ├── chapterbib
│   │   │   ├── cite
│   │   │   ├── color
│   │   │   ├── comma
│   │   │   ├── csquotes
│   │   │   ├── deleq
│   │   │   ├── drftcite
│   │   │   ├── dropping
│   │   │   ├── enumerate
│   │   │   ├── eqlist
│   │   │   ├── eqparbox
│   │   │   ├── everyshi
│   │   │   ├── exmpl
│   │   │   ├── fixme
│   │   │   ├── flafter
│   │   │   ├── float
│   │   │   ├── floatflt
│   │   │   ├── fn2end
│   │   │   ├── footmisc
│   │   │   ├── geometry
│   │   │   ├── german
│   │   │   ├── graphicx
│   │   │   ├── graphpap
│   │   │   ├── harpoon
│   │   │   ├── hhline
│   │   │   ├── histogram
│   │   │   ├── hyperref
│   │   │   ├── ifthen
│   │   │   ├── inputenc
│   │   │   ├── letterspace
│   │   │   ├── lineno
│   │   │   ├── longtable
│   │   │   ├── lscape
│   │   │   ├── manyfoot
│   │   │   ├── moreverb
│   │   │   ├── multibox
│   │   │   ├── multicol
│   │   │   ├── newalg
│   │   │   ├── ngerman
│   │   │   ├── numprint
│   │   │   ├── oldstyle
│   │   │   ├── outliner
│   │   │   ├── overcite
│   │   │   ├── pagenote
│   │   │   ├── parallel
│   │   │   ├── plain
│   │   │   ├── plates
│   │   │   ├── polski
│   │   │   ├── psgo
│   │   │   ├── schedule
│   │   │   ├── SIunits
│   │   │   ├── textfit
│   │   │   ├── times
│   │   │   ├── tipa
│   │   │   ├── ulem
│   │   │   ├── url
│   │   │   ├── verbatim
│   │   │   └── version
│   │   ├── packages.vim
│   │   ├── projecttemplate.vim
│   │   ├── pytools.py
│   │   ├── smartspace.vim
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── article.tex
│   │   │   ├── IEEEtran.tex
│   │   │   ├── report.tex
│   │   │   └── report_two_column.tex
│   │   ├── templates.vim
│   │   ├── texmenuconf.vim
│   │   ├── texproject.vim
│   │   ├── texrc
│   │   ├── texviewer.vim
│   │   ├── version.vim
│   │   └── wizardfuncs.vim
│   └── tex_latexSuite.vim
├── indent
│   └── tex.vim
├── latextags
├── ltags
├── Makefile
├── Makefile.in
└── plugin
    ├── filebrowser.vim
    ├── imaps.vim
    ├── libList.vim
    ├── remoteOpen.vim
    └── SyntaxFolds.vim
```

Now, I'll simply get the whole `vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956` directory and move/copy it inside `~/.vim/bundle`.

If you want to open `~/.vim/bundle` in Finder, just type

```
open ~/.vim/bundle
```

and you will get a nice file manager to help you.

That's how `pathogen` works for virtually all plugins. Note that `vim-latex` requires you [to set some settings](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html) in your `.vimrc`. Just repeat

```
open -e ~/.vimrc
```

and add stuff after the `pathogen` line.

I really hope my answer helps. `:)`

Comment: Upon launching MacVim after following your instructions, I get ```Error detected while processing /Users/alexmayorov/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()```

Comment: Hi @AlexMayorov! I think `pathogen` probably got updated and that method is now gone. I am currently unavailable to test things out (as I am in the middle of a conference), but I will try to come back at it later. Sorry.

Comment: @PauloCereda- Thanks a lot for the detail description! BTW, I also got in message as at-GingerBadger mentioned above. It was resolved by using the curl command that at-dowewas wrote below.

Answer (score 1):

The curl command given gave me a blank `pathogen.vim` file. I had to use the following command.

`curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you be so kind to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Note that this comment is in reference to Paulo Cereda's comment.

Comment: This worked for me.