# Error installing Vim-LaTeX using Pathogen on MacVim

Tags: installing, vim

I installed vim-latex using pathogen following the very clear instructions proposed in:
[How to install vim-latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/how-to-install-vim-latex)

However, when I open a .tex file using MacVim, I get the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/texviewer.vim:
line  728:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/valeria/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/outline.py", line 12, in <module>
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named StringIO
Error detected while processing /Users/valeria/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim:
line 1040:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/valeria/.vim/bundle/vim-latex-1.8.23-20130116.788-git2ef9956/ftplugin/latex-suite/pytools.py", line 1, in <module>
import string, vim, re, os, glob
ImportError: No module named string
```

I don't really know if it helps, but since `import StringIO` looked like python syntax, I checked on the shell to see if my python had such module and it does.

I am using MacVim on a Mac running Mavericks. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that macvim was not binding correctly to python. This sequence of commands solved it on yosemite for me, and made automatic latex plugin work as well:
1) brew install macvim
2) brew linkapps macvim
3) easy_install pip
4) pip install psutil

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might be a solution, but could you elaborate on your post a little bit?