# How can I install vim-latex on mac os x?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I was trying to install vim-latex (http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download)

1. My Vim comes with the OS X system and is located at `/usr/share/vim/vim73`
2. According to the instruction, I created a folder as `~/.vim` and unzip the source file into directory `~/.vim`
3. Then I create a file `.vimrc` at `~/` with the following content:

   REQUIRED. This makes vim invoke LaTeX-Suite when you open a TeX file.

   ```
   filetype plugin on
   ```

   IMPORTANT: Win32 users will need to have `shellslash` set so that LaTeX
   can be called correctly.

   ```
   set shellslash
   ```

   IMPORTANT: `grep` will sometimes skip displaying the file name if you
   search in a single file. This will confuse LaTeX-Suite. Set your `grep`
   program to always generate a file-name.

   ```
   set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
   ```

   OPTIONAL: This enables automatic indentation as you type.

   ```
   filetype indent on
   ```

   OPTIONAL: Starting with Vim 7, the `filetype` of empty `.tex` files defaults to
   `plaintex` instead of `tex`, which results in vim-latex not being loaded.
   The following changes the default filetype back to `tex`:

   ```
   let g:tex_flavor='latex'
   ```

   I also `cd` into `~/.vim/ftplugin/` to create a file `tex.vim` with the following content:
   this is mostly a matter of taste. but LaTeX looks good with just a bit
   of indentation.

   ```
   set sw=2
   ```

   TIP: if you write your `\label`'s as `\label{fig:something}`, then if you
   type in `\ref{fig:` and press C-n you will automatically cycle through
   all the figure labels. Very useful!

   ```
   set iskeyword+=:
   ```
4. In the command line I start vim and type:

   ```
   :helptags ~/.vim/doc
   ```

Nothing really happens. And I simply don't know how to continue.

Could you please tell me what should I do next to make it works?

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/how-to-install-vim-latex) ? Could you be more specific about how you tested that nothing happened ? For instance if you open a file foo.tex and press <F5>, nothing special happens ? You could first check that the `~/.vimrc` you created is indeed that used by vim typing `:version` and checking that the file mentioned is indeed the one you created

Comment: I suggest to check the required folder structure for the plugins to be read... also, you sould check the link recommended by @VincentNivoliers