# Configuring vim-latex when installed using pathogen

Tags: vim, unix, vim-latex

I've followed the instructions in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/how-to-install-vim-latex) to install `vim-latex` using [`pathogen`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).

Now I'd like to have `vim-latex` compile using `pdflatex` instead of the default `latex`.

The instructions [on the `vim-latex` page](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-latex-suite.html) refer to creating a file called:

> `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim`, where `$VIM` corresponds to `~/.vim` for *nix
>   machines and `~/vimfiles` for windows machines

Where should this file go when I'm using `pathogen`, and hence have no `$VIM/ftplugin` folder, rather a `$VIM/bundle/` folder?

Comment: Creating the `$VIM/ftplugin` directory and creating `tex.vim` file in that directory should still work.

Comment: To add to @Aditya's comment, you **should** use the `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim` file because (I think) changes to files in `$VIM/bundle/` may be modified when you update your vim plugins.

Comment: Either of you two want to put this in an answer and I'll accept? (I never understand why people put rep-worthy answers in comments!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Aditya's comment, you should use `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim`, creating the `$VIM/ftplugin` directory if required.

Although `$VIM/bundle/vim-latex/ftplugin/tex.vim` does the same job, you should avoid modifying files in `$VIM/bundle` because they *may* be overwritten when you update your vim plugins.