# Vim-latex vs TexLive on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vim-latex

I'm new to Ubuntu and uses LaTeX a lot. 
I heard people recommend Vim-latex for me but also heard that TeXLive works well too.
What are some pros and cons for both? (Assume that I have some experience with terminal, visual editing and vim)

Also, Vim-LaTeX suite installation is still opaque to me. Can someone give me some instructions more?

Thanks!

Comment: First decide if you like writing and editing files using [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/), which is a text editor. If you do, then the [`Vim-LaTeX`](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) plugin may well appeal to you as the best way to write and edit `.tex` files. But on Ubuntu, you could try other editors as well: [`gedit`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) (which also has a plugin), [`GNU Emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), and dozens of others. Consult [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/8528) to get a bettter sense. **But, regardless,** you will need to install TeX Live.

Comment: Perhaps, you are asking for a comparison between vim-latex and other possible `ide-like' interfaces like texstudio. In that case, it is better to edit the question. For installation of vim-latex suite, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112698/157031 (though this question is about Mac OS, the solution  with pathogen should work in linux too)

Answer (score 5):

TeXLive is the distribution that contains the Tex, latex and many other programs and all the packages.

Vim-LaTeX is a Vim plugin for writing Latex documents. You need a Tex distribution, such as TeXLive for it to work.

There's nothing to compare between the two.

Comment: Vim-TeX is a Vim plugin for writing LaTeX-ready documents. You need a Tex distribution, such as TeXLive to render them (e.g. as Pdf documents).

Comment: @marsupilam Thanks for the explanation! What is a LaTeX-ready document? Is it files in .tex format? What does Vim-LaTex allow me to do actually (editing tex file in vim? Or does it just give me vim key-binding)?

Comment: LaTex-ready = LaTeX source file (".tex file"). Vim-LaTeX has several functions to it : helpful vim keybindings for LaTeX, and latex-mk compilation functions helping you to dynamically visualize your produced Pdf file (but I don't know exactly about vim-LaTeX).First you should learn to produce simple LaTeX documents (Wikipedia is helpful here) before you bother with vim-LaTeX, imho)

Comment: Not that it's the source of the OP's confusion, but  vim-LaTeX and vimtex are two different vim plugins (for writing tex files), neither go by vim-TeX to my knowledge.