# How do I know if vim-latex is installed correctly?

Tags: mac, vim, vim-latex

I followed the very clear instructions [How to install vim-latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112698/how-to-install-vim-latex). I did not encounter any error while installing, but when I open a test file with `vim test.tex` the interface still looks like normal vim. 
How can I confirm that vim-latex was installed correctly?

I am running macOS 10.13.6.

Also, what's the difference between vim, on the macOS command line, and MacVim, the standalone application?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!  We tend to like one question at a time here, and anyway your second question is a bit off topic.  That said, MacVim is a full graphical version of vim that lets you use the system founts and in particular lets you use the mouse. The clipboard is marginally better integrated with the OS as well.  And it tends to be more up to date with core vim, than the vim supplied with the OS: 7.4.8056 v 8.1.72 on my system.  Otherwise they are much the same...

Comment: Thruston, sorry, I should have reviewed the question posting guidelines. Thanks for answering my second question! I couldn't find a clear description of its purpose. That does sound beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=manual&title=Tutorial#tutorial) suggests you should try

```
:help latex-suite.txt
```

from the Vim command line.  If you have not installed it, you will get an apology from vim

```
E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt
```